# hibernate execute native SQL with uncertainty parameters,works in mysql but not in oracle

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, hibernate

I have complete a web project that users can custom and execute SQL statements with parameters in javascript use dwr:

```
var htId='htId00001';
var id='id001';
var params=[{"key":"id","value":[id]},{"key":"regDate","value":['2013-12-31 23:59:59']}]; //define the parameters
var sql="select * from sms_contracts sc_id='"+htId+"' and id = :id and regDate < :regDate";
moon.dbUtil.doSQLExcute(sql,params,function(datas){
    if(datas.rows.length>0){
        //do something here
    }
});
```

and there is some methods like :

```
public List executeQueryBySql(String SQL, List<Param> params) {
    //here I create a SQLQuery use the 'SQL' argument.
    Query query = getSession4Map().createSQLQuery(SQL);
    //put the 'params' argument dynamicly 
    for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
        Param param = params.get(i);
        if (param.getValue() instanceof List<?>) {
            List<?> list = param.getValue();
            if (list.size() > 1) {
                query.setParameterList(param.getKey(),(ArrayList<Object>) list);
            } else {
                Object obj = list.get(0);
                query.setParameter(param.getKey(), obj);
            }
        }
    }
    return query.list();
}
```

the class 'Param' definition:

```
public class Param {
    String key;
    List<String> value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
    public List<String> getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(List<String> value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

it works well when I use mysql,
but when I change database to oracle, I get an error 
'String can not convert to java.util.Date' (for example the 'regDate' condition above)
or 
'String can not convert to java.lang.Long'
...

I do not want to change 
'setParameter(String name, Object val)'
to 
'setParameter(String name, Object val, Type type)'
because there are many history-data

what should I do? Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Is table structure same for both the dbs?

Comment: in mysql it is 'datetime'.
in oracle it is 'TIMESTAMP(6)'.

i use hibernate.

Comment: I think you should put `java.util.Date` to the parameter map instead of using a `String`.

Comment: but there are other parameters that user can custom dynamic. it can be Int,String,Date,Clob

Comment: i want user can custom their db operation by using SQL statement in javascript.